# Does left-exactness imply semi-additivity?

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ be pre-additive (enriched over the abelian groups) categories and $F : \mathcal C \Rightarrow \mathcal D$ a functor which is left-exact in the sense that it preserves kernels (or, equivalently, equalizers). Can we prove that $F$ is semi-additive in the sense that $F(f + g) = F(f) + F(g)$ without assuming that the categories have finite products or biproducts?

Comment: Even, If you assune the categories has biproduct, I don't see how this is sufficient if left exact only means preserves kernel. If left exact means preserve finite limite then of course as it will preserves biproduct, but I don't see how Kernel enough would be enough. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Preserving kernels is enough to show that it preserves products as well, but it's not a trivial construction, trying to find a public source for it...

Comment: Ok. I wan't aware of this, but that does sound reasonable given that matrix multiplication encodes the addition in various ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I don't know if assuming biproducts exists is enough or not but preserving kernel alone is not enough. Here is a counter-exemple. Let $C$ be the pre-additive category with only one object $*$ and such that $Hom(*,*) = \mathbb{Z}$.

If we want, we can add a zero object to $C$ if we want $C$ to have all kernel.

I fix $\sigma$ a non-trivial bijection of the set of prime number. consider the following functor $F:C \to C$ defined as follow : on objects $F(*) = *$ (and $F(0) = 0 $). And on morphism:

$$F(0) = 0$$
$$ F(\pm p_1^{a_1} \dots p_n^{a_n} ) = \pm \sigma(p_1)^{a_1} \dots \sigma(p_n)^{a_n} $$

We extend it to the $0$ object in the only way possible. Then $F$ is clearly a functor, but it is not additive unless $\sigma$ is the identity.

And $F$ preserves all kernel : any arrow $ n: * \to *$ has kernel 0 if $ n \neq 0$ and kernel $*$ (with the identity map) if $n=0$ and in both case this is preserved by $F$. This also works for the arrows $0 : * \to 0$ and $ 0 : 0 \to *$ and $1=0 : 0 \to 0 $.

In fact even more simply, given that $F$ come from an automorphism of the monoid $(\mathbb{Z}, \times)$ it is (part of) an equivalence of categories, and hence preserve all limits and colimits that exists.

Comment: Instead of kernel $\mathbb Z$ you mean $*$? It's not obvious to me though that besides the kernel objects it also preserves the kernel morphisms?

Comment: Yes sorry I mean $*$. Well the kernel morphism are either the unique map from $0$ to $*$ or the identity of $*$ and both are preserved by $F$. You can also use that $F$ is an equivalence of categories.

Comment: Ah right, thanks!